# Binding Hashtable to a WPF Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, hashtable

Please tell me how can i bind a hashtable to  a WPF Combobox. I cannot find the DisplayMember,ValueMember properties in the WPF Combobox class.

Please advice.

Regards,
John.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward. Here's an example

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyHashTable}"
                  SelectedValuePath="Key"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> MyHashTable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyHashTable = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        MyHashTable.Add("Key 1", "Value 1");
        MyHashTable.Add("Key 2", "Value 2");
        MyHashTable.Add("Key 3", "Value 3");
        MyHashTable.Add("Key 4", "Value 4");
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```